# How to access the view page from a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been tasked w/porting an older ASPX app to .NET MVC, and then doing some work on it.

This has been fraught with peril; not the least of my troubles is that the APSX events won't propagate in this framework (using ViewPage for the aspx.cs file - MVC 4 demands it)

I.E. - an asp:Button with a defined click event won't fire that click event anymore.

What prompted this particular question is this - I've got an asp:table that I want to reload when certain actions happen in the controller. In the code behind file, I've got a method that handles that, and it gets called from Page_Load, just fine.

But in the controller, I need to find a way to get a handle on that page itself and invoke that method. I can get a new instance of the page, but that instance won't have the table already instantiated.

How, in the controller, can I get a hold of the ViewPage created for that method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't think about MVC that way. There are no click events like you think of them when you think ASP.NET.

read these

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp

you might find some joy with them

these will help too

[Migrating from ASP.NET WebForms to MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522841/migrating-from-asp-net-webforms-to-mvc)

and [Migrating legacy ASP.NET to MVC 2 (RC): HttpApplication events not firing, User principal is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979066/migrating-legacy-asp-net-to-mvc-2-rc-httpapplication-events-not-firing-user)